# Two different sign up forms but one login for both using mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, authentication, mongoose, basic-authentication

I am developing a system whereby users can register as either a Category A member or a Category B member. I have 2 different signup forms for that with different schemas.

Now, I want to have a single login system for both types of accounts. But the **catch here is** that the users **should** be able to sign up for both the categories using the **same email address**. I am not sure how that is possible.

Things to consider -

1. If the user signs up for category A and then signs up for Category B, then what will be the new password? How will we make it out on the backend that it's actually the owner of the account who's willing to register for the other category and not some random person doing that
2. My backend also sends out verification emails though. Maybe I could add some field to the existing category entry in MongoDB like **requestedOtherCategory: true** in the database and upon email confirmation, I map both those accounts so that they have a single login, but how do I determine the password thing?
3. I could build a POST-LOGIN signup form from the dashboard. Something that allows registered users to sign up for the other category from within their dashboard itself, but I'm not sure if I want to make major changes to my application at this point.

Thanks so much for all the help.

Comment: A fact to keep in mind is that if the user successfully registers for the second account, the passwords for both accounts should be exactly the same. An approach would be to allow two passwords for the same accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could give users who are already registered to create a profile for category b so when they log in they could just pick the profile they prefer to use. There is clearly no right answer here, but it is one of the possible approaches

Comment: That is one possible approach yes, however, again, I don't want to give the users functionality to create the profile for second category from within the dashboard. It will just confuse the user. (As a user, I don't like **a single thing** being present in multiple forms at **different places**)